# Why are users rejecting valid retags?

Tags: discussion, tags, rejected-edits, suggested-edits

I changed the tags of questions about ETW Eventsource from [eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventsource) to [etw-eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etw-eventsource) and some users rejected them as too minor an only 2 edits were approved by educated users. Both tags are 2 different things and to highlight this difference I changed the tags but the suggested edit was rejected.

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5095460
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5095455
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5095452

If I'm unsure on an edit on superuser.com, I simply press "Skip" and don't reject valid edits where I'm unsure.

Why are there many users who reject valid retags when they have no idea about the difference between those tags?

Comment: You should stop calling people trolls and idiots if you wish to start a constructive discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suspect that the edits were rejected because the reviewers thought that there were probably other edits that could have been made to the questions other than changing the tags.

If you really can't see anything else that needs fixing then move onto the next question and wait until you get 2,000 reputation when you'll be able to retag to your heart's content.

Comment: no, I only hanged the tags, and nothing else. See the examples. Some good users approved them and others not. Can mods approve them after a reject? or do I ave to make the edits again?

Comment: @magicandre1981 that's the point. The reviewers obviously thought that you'd missed other edits you should have made.

Comment: I can't add other edits. What else should I change? There is nothing to change except the **wrong** tag!!!!

Comment: @magicandre1981 - in that case **don't edit**. Just move onto another possible edit. You could leave a comment.

Comment: "Just move onto another possible edit. You could leave a comment." Please explain this more. I have no idea what you want to tell me.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - If the only thing you think is wrong with a question is that it has the wrong tags **don't make the suggested edit**. If it's really important then you *might* think about leaving a comment explaining that it has the wrong tags and then either the OP or someone with > 2,000 rep will see it and make the edit for you.

Comment: ok, I learned my lesson today, that the approval process is primarily based on Opinions and I'll never ever again make an edit again.  Question is answered for me. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 14):

> Why are there many users who reject valid retags when they have no idea about the difference between those tags?

How are people supposed to know what it is about when you haven't made an effort to explain the tag.  [etw-eventsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etw-eventsource) doesn't event have a tag wiki yet.  Before going around and mass adding it to questions, your first step should always been to make sure it has a good tag wiki so users know how to use the tag.

A good reviewer, if he/she isn't familiar with the topic, is going to review the wiki to see if it applies but without a wiki, they can't evaluate the necessity of the tag.

---

Now this isn't to say that the tag wiki is the only problem here, but it can help.

Retag only edits (and other similarly minor edits) are a hot button issue.  Many reviewers see users who make mass retag **suggested** edits as farming rep, which is a significant problem on Stack Overflow.  We are trying to encourage reviewers to reject more edits to prevent people from spamming the review queue with dozens of the same insignificant edit and leaving other problems in the post.

When the same reviewers start seeing your name in 3 or 4 consecutive suggested edit reviews doing the same exact thing and leaving other problems, they are going to start hitting reject more often.

Because of this, mass retagging is often best left to 2K users as it doesn't need to go into the review queue.