# Is this retagging invalid?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Some minutes ago, I edited the following question by removing the tags [openstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack), [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services).

[Can every d3 chard drawn by rickshaw for cloud-computing software platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871915/can-every-d3-chard-drawn-by-rickshaw-for-cloud-computing-software-platform)

The user rejected this edit and edited his question providing the reason of the reject

> I have included tags openstack and amazon-web-services because they are cloud-computing platform.

My answer to this (also added as a comment to the original question) and the initial reason for retaging is

> Hello sir, I think this not the way that tags work. Tags have to be related to your problem in order to help people filter, find and answer your question. For example, (in your case) if I replicate your issue to my local development machine the problem will be the same. So it does not have to do with openstack or amazon-web-services. If you see what questions are under the openstack tag, I think it will be more clear to you.

Q1: Who is right? Am I wrong for retaging and why?

Q2: Is there a chat-room to solve such matters, in order not to post it in meta?

Note #1

I am aware of the following meta posts and I agree that just a retaging can be consider a minor edit. But in this spesific case I think IMHO the are not other changes to be made in the question and the 'rejection' reason is not valid.

- [Retag rejected during review as too minor edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270158/retag-rejected-during-review-as-too-minor-edit)
- [Why are users rejecting valid retags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260985/why-are-users-rejecting-valid-retags)